# Change mac terminal settings from the command line

Tags: mac, bash, terminal

I can change the appearance of Terminal by typing <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>i</kbd> and picking from the list of saved settings.

Is it also possible to do this directly from the command line? I would like to write a bash script that, among other things, will change the appearance of the terminal.

If not, I know that it is also possible to change the shell's appearance by setting environment variables. Does this relate in any way to what happens when I pick a new set of settings from the list of saved settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to set current settings of window 1 to settings set "Grass"'`

Comment: what crazy language... ?